# VSCode with Python Extension April 2019 - "Python Extension Loading..."

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-python

I am unable to get Python extension working with fresh install of  VS Code /  Python 3.7.3 on Windows 10.

VS Code status bar shows a message 'Python extension loading...' continuously.

Python is installed in a non-standard path at c:\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python

Have uninstalled both VSCode and python several times and had  installed afresh.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>which python
/c/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python
```

When developer tools is opened, the following error shows up in console.

```
property 'length' of undefined
    at g.update (c:\Users\APCIT\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.11987\out\client\extension.js:83:373818)
    at g.initialize (c:\Users\APCIT\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.11987\out\client\extension.js:83:381134)
    at new g (c:\Users\APCIT\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.11987\out\client\extension.js:83:372522)
    at Function.getInstance (c:\Users\APCIT\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.11987\out\client\extension.js:83:372729)
    at h.getSettings (c:\Users\APCIT\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.11987\out\client\extension.js:83:370264)
    at b.initialize (c:\Users\APCIT\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.11987\out\client\extension.js:83:624877)
    at c:\Users\APCIT\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.11987\out\client\extension.js:9:93210
    at c:\Users\APCIT\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.11987\out\client\extension.js:9:93877
    at module.exports.t.activate (c:\Users\APCIT\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.11987\out\client\extension.js:9:96601)
    at Function._callActivateOptional (c:\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:719:166)
    at Function._callActivate (c:\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:718:872)
    at define._doActivateExtension.Promise.all.then.e (c:\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:718:79)
```

[image]

Comment: No worries. If you want, you can re-post it yourself, and I will delete my "community wiki" copy (we encourage self-answers here). You might get votes on it over time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

OK - I deleted the VS Code profile folder

```
'%APPDATA%\Roaming\Code
```

and installed fresh extension along with miniconda, and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an annoying problem that is caused by other extensions. Best way I fixed mine was:

1. To disable all the extensions
2. Enable ms-python extension
3. Reload vs-code and voila, it's all fixed

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. But I fixed it by changing the location of the python file.